# how to find non-alphanumeric in C

Tags: c

im trying to separate non-alphanumeric and alphanumeric from a string in C.this is my current code,but if i use this,it will detect all alphanumeric only,while at non-alphanumeric it will return null.so i cant detect at what index are all the non-alphanumeric at.

```
    char data[] = "http://www.google.com";
    char key[]  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    char *find;

    find = strpbrk(data,key);
    while(find != NULL){
        printf("%c",*find);
        find = strpbrk(find+1,key);        
    }
```

The output will be httpwwwgooglecom.Thats is what i partially want. i also trying to find where are all the non-alphanumeric at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the C [isalpha](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) family of routines.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, it is just easier to do the work yourself.  And yes, for the specific case of A-Za-z0-9, you should use isalnum() instead of strchr().

```
for(c=data;*c;c++)
{
  if (!strchr(key,*c))
   {
     // Do something with non-alpha
   }
   else
   {
      printf("%c",*c);
   }
}
```

Comment: would be easier,only if i know. i did regex,and all of functions in string.h lib.didnt know got other lib too.thnx for helping.im still learning :)