# C: Remove symbols from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, symbols

May I know if there is any way to remove non-alphabetical symbols from a string in C?

For instance I have an `char array[5][5]` with: `"hi", "my..", "name", "is,,", "bob!"`

Desired output: `"hi", "my", "name", "is", "bob"`

Is there anyway to remove the symbols?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. I suggest that you put in an effort to do it and see what you come up with before asking at SO, the purpose of which is not to write your code for you. However, to help you out, look into ctype.h

Comment: BTW, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433866/how-to-find-non-alphanumeric-in-c which I found by searching SO for [c] alphanumeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
void keepalnum(char *src) {
    unsigned char *dest = src;
    while ((*dest = *src++))
        dest += isalnum(*dest) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The idea is to advance the source pointer after each copy, but move the destination pointer only when you see an alphanumeric character.

Here is how you use it:

```
char str[] = "quick-brown fox jumps? over the.. lazy dog!";
keepalnum(str);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

This [prints](http://ideone.com/Ynx1H)

```
quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
```

Comment: This is certainly not the sort of code I would offer to a neophyte ... nor is it the sort of code I would write myself. It's even buggy, as one should never pass a char to isalnum. More straightforward and without the extra stores and the bug is (sorry, no formatting): `unsigned char c; while ( (c = *src++) != '\0' ) if(isalnum(c)) *dest++ = c; *dest = '\0';`

Comment: @JimBalter My solution does not differ much from the last version of `strcpy` from K&R's book, chapter five. I believe that intimate familiarity with K&R is required of anyone who wishes to do any type of programming in C. But I'm trying to avoid setting the bar too high: for instance, in my code I'd prefer `dest += !!isalnum(*dest)` instead of the ternary operator, but that would be too much to digest in one go.

Comment: I've been writing C code since before even the first edition of K&R was published. It's an excellent resource, but not the final word on coding technique. And your code wouldn't pass my review or even my interview.

Comment: @JimBalter What can I say... I guess I should be glad that I'm not submitting my code to you for reviews :) As far as alleged bugginess goes, would you mind providing a sample string for which my code would fail?

Comment: Any string containing a char with a value outside of 0-127 in an implementation in which char is signed *may* fail because it violates the requirement that the argument to isalnum must be representable as an unsigned char. In some implementations it will cause a memory fault.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm yet to find a platform where it would matter, but since [the standard does say so](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.4), it's an easy fix. I edited the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would know whether it matters on platforms you have used. I know it does matter on some platforms because I've seen their implementations of isalnum and was a member of X3J11 and know that the unsigned char requirement was motivated by such platforms ... which included Bell Labs UNIX.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm guessing that the "unsigned char or EOF" language has been added to the standard to avoid breaking pre-existing macro-based implementations that rely on lookup tables: passing a negative value would effectively pass a negative array index, causing a segfault. I haven't seen such implementations in a while, though.

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen an implementation of isalnum in which it is not a macro that indexes an array. The GNU implementation is of that sort, except that it indexes the middle of the array so that both EOF and buggy code using negative indices work. From ctype.h: "we also support negative `signed char' values for broken old programs"

Comment: `dest += (*dest > 0 && isalnum(*dest)) ? 1 : 0;` would fix it.

Comment: @wildplasser I have already fixed it in a trivial edit 11 hours ago :)

Comment: Oops, I had not seen the pointer alias ;-) It is even more trivial than mine. Would not you also add the *register* keyword, just to please @JimBalter  :-? BTW, for wakkerbot, I attacked the problem by wrapping is...() into a bunch of ugly macros. I think I removed them afterwards.

Comment: @wildplasser The register keyword is useless and it would be foolish and irrational to think that anything I have said implies that adding one would please me. It's funny how some people react to someone pointing out that their code is buggy because of unawareness of basic issues in the language; passing char to isalnum potentially results in UB and every competent professional C programmer I know is aware of that.

Comment: @JimBalter "It's funny how some people react to someone pointing out that their code is buggy" On the other hand, the entertainment value of watching people trying to describe an issue that [has been fixed "a while ago"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176336/c-remove-symbols-from-a-string/11176622#comment14671052_11176622) as something of relevance should not be underestimated either.

Comment: Your comment is a non sequitur as only wildplasser commented on what had already been fixed. It's also an example of a tu quoque fallacy.

Comment: @JimBalter "only wildplasser commented on what had already been fixed" I meant your specific comment where you mentioned the "we also support negative `signed char` values for broken old programs". I added a hyperlink to your comment, but it's easy to miss because of SO's formatting. The reference to "tu quoque" went completely over my head, though: I know what that fallacy is, but I fail to see how it is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the C `isalnum(int ch);` you can remove filter values that are neither numbers nor characters like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN 5
#define STR_LEN 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;

    char array[5][5];
    char out_str[5] = {0};

    int array_idx, str_idx, cpy_idx;

    strcpy(array[0], "hi");
    strcpy(array[1], "my..");
    strcpy(array[2], "name");
    strcpy(array[3], "is,,");
    strcpy(array[4], "bob!");

    for(array_idx=0; array_idx < ARRAY_LEN; array_idx++)
    {
        cpy_idx = 0;

        for(str_idx=0; str_idx < STR_LEN; str_idx++)
        {
            if(isalnum(array[array_idx][str_idx]))
            {
                out_str[cpy_idx++]= array[array_idx][str_idx];
            }
        }

        out_str[cpy_idx++] = '\0';
        printf("%s ", out_str);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return rc;
}
```

This example lacks end bounds checking, because the example was coded around 4-character strings plus a terminating 0. In practice, I declare buffers that are larger than the largest string I plan to handle, but I still count the characters being copied, which was not done here.